# Bar chart in tableau

Tags: python, sql, excel, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have 2 columns states and number of accidents, i want to create a bar chart with top 5 states with number of accidents. But with that i also want uttarakhand whether it comes in top 5 or not . How to do that in tableau

I have tried rank function but didn’t get proper output. Can anyone help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged so many tags. Is this in Excel?

Make an helper array for chart data using `SORT` formula and use `TAKE` to take 5 highest:

```
=TAKE(SORT(A1:B10,2,-1),5)
```

Use this data to make a chart.

Use this to lookup if state is in new array (formula in `B14`):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A14,INDEX(D1#,,1),0))
```

Result:

[image]